# How do I prevent ECMAScript modules from mutating the global object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

ECMAScript modules are a great native solution to implement modularity and isolation between modules. However, this code has a possibility of existing in a module:

```
window.foo = 'bar';
```

How can I guarantee that a module I'm importing won't mutate the global object (which defeats the concept of the module), leading to unpredictable behaviors in my app?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. I'd love to be wrong though.

Comment: I'm not sure either, would love to be wrong too!

Comment: Is this for security, or more for sanity checking?

Comment: @loganfsmyth when I import some libraries in my app as ECMAScript modules, I expect them not to have unwanted interactions with my own code or with other libraries, which I can't guarantee since the global scope is uncontrollable. Languages like Java or .NET have the code enclosed in classes so you need at least references to the classes in order to interact with them. In JavaScript, even when using ECMAScript modules, the global scope is freely readable and mutable by everyone and I'd like to know if there is something to mitigate this.

Comment: Do you have example of a module being mutated?

Comment: If you're bundling your code, then you can transform each module into something like `(function (window) { /* module code dumped here */})({})` to provide a fake window to the bundled code. However, I'm not sure if any bundler makes this transformation easy. Also, it might break some modules if they are trying to read a value from `window`. I guess a more elaborate setup would be making something like a read-only `window` object or even more transparently, one which has all the values of the global window and a private set of values for each module. Probably not trivial, though.